# XCode How to organise assets in folders

Tags: ios, xcode, assets

I'm working on an app that has a lot of assets. Most of them are .png skins for the app.
I'd like to be able to organise those assets in some logical way. Currently I have them all
in ASSETS\SKINS\ folder and I was wondering if there's any way to keep it that way. I mean to have that kind of folder structure so I could make skin loading automatic by listing the ASSETS\SKINS folder and assuming that all available folders contain skin definitions.

Flexibility is important here, because I'll be adding and removing skins all the time and I need to detect the available ones in runtime.

(EDIT) it's ok if all I have to do is just *add the ASSETS folder the the project*

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Have you checked out asset catalogs? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html

Comment: yeah, I have, but after I tried to add the asset folder to a catalog, it kinda lost the folder structure. maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"SOME_EXTENSION"
    inDirectory:@"YOUR_DIRECTORY_PATH"];
```

to get an array of paths to files with the given extension.

Comment: Is it enough to add folder to the project to use this? If so, then how should I specify the directory? I couldn't get anything that way..

Comment: Are you talking about a folder in the Xcode organizer?  Or a folder on your computer?  For a file to be included in your build, it must be added to the project.  You can't just move files around on your computer.

Comment: ya, I have a filesystem directory which I added to the project.